# How can logging to Crashlytics be done from C++ code on iOS?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

The Crashlytics [documentation for iOS](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html) only mentions custom logging from Swift and Objective-C. It mentions nothing about doing this from C++. [On Android](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html), we can use the `log()` and `set()` functions from the Crashlytics [native header](http://download.crashlytics.com/android/ndk/crashlytics.h) to do logging from C++ code called through the JNI. Is there an equivalent method for iOS? Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, I don't think there is a C-function for that but I had the problem some time ago and I used a function pointer. So here it is.

In the C scope (.cpp and .h file)

```
    void yourCFunction(void (*logFunc)(const char*) = NULL);
```

In the ObjectiveC scope:

```
CYourCClass *yourCClass = [...];
yourCClass->yourCFunction( [](const char* t){
    CLS_LOG(@"%s", t);
});
```

To call the log function in C++:

```
if (logFunc!=NULL) {
    std::string debugChr("Some message");
    (*logFunc)(debugChr.c_str());
}
```

This can be improved using macro and stuff but you have the idea.

Comment: Thank you. I did something similar, but with a callback to Swift instead of Objective-C. I guess since logging to Crashlytics is equally easy on both, it doesn't matter which one you choose.

Comment: @JaidevRamakrishna possible to provide example with callback to Swift?

Answer (score 2):

Todd from Crashlytics here! Right now this is not possible without some sort of custom adapter on your end to go back to Swift or Objective-C. As C++ becomes more common in advanced apps I'd expect to see the team consider this :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Can you tell me what such an adapter would look like? I am thinking of a C++ singleton that wraps a call to 'Crashlytics.sharedInstance()' on the Swift side, that can be passed around on the C++ side of things. Does this sound plausible?

Comment: Yes, that should work, however your stack traces might not be as readable as you'd hope. They should still provide value and logs and keys will be intact.

Comment: @ToddBurner does crashlytics still report if we had a crash in iOS C++ code just doesn't show the stack trace ?